# what is the matrix norm of a matrix respect to other vector norm

Tags: matrices

what can we say about 
$$||A|| = max\{||Ax||_{\infty}:||x||_1=1\}$$
and about
$$||A|| = max\{||Ax||_1:||x||_{\infty}=1\}$$
I proved that in the first case $||A|| = max\{|a_{ij}|\}$ since
$$||Ax|| = x_1A_1 + x_2A_2 + ... + x_nA_n$$
where $A_i$ is the ith column of A and 
$$x = (x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_n)^T$$
so 
$$||Ax|| \leq |x_1|.||A_1||_{\infty} + |x_2|.||A_2||_{\infty} + ... + |x_n|.||A_n||_{\infty}$$
$$\leq (|x_1| + |x_2| + ... + |x_n|)max||A_i||_{\infty} = max||A_i||_{\infty} = max\{|a_{ij}|\}$$
and it is easy to see that this bound can be obtained but what about second case please help me.